# Меч-кладенец

Tags: этимология, лексика

Что означает слово "кладенец"? Подозреваю, что это от слова "класть", но как это относится к мечу?

Comment: "Мы" слишком хорошо знаем иностранные языки. Нельзя мехагнически переносить значение даже созвучного слова на другой язык. 
А уж каким боком ваше "плакированный" к русскому языку пришить - и вовсе непонятно...

Comment: Сама версия, что на меч что-то "наклали", в общем-то не противоречит логике, но как и все остальные небезупречна. В данном случае - упирается в семантику суффикса "-ец". У него несколько возможных значений: качество, состояние и т.д.: варенец, холодец, леденец, боец, удалец, горец, ларец и т.д., но вот подходящего - "то, куда направлено действие" - я что-то не вижу. Если вспомните - подет интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.
Насколько знаю, "Кладенцами" называли дорогие двуручные мечи из особой стали.
Корень, очевидно, "клад", "класть".
Сталь (или один из видов) на Руси называлась укладом. А меч из такой стали - **укладенец**. Вопрос только в том, откуда само это слово взялось, *уклад*.

Знаю несколько версий об этом и о мече вообще. Все - сомнительны.  
В Интернете есть ещё, но совсем малоправдоподобные.

~1. Меч всех *кладёт* всех вокруг. Народная этимология, не более.
~2. Клад - в дорогих украшениях. Проблема в том, что эти украшения совсем необязательны.
Да и не называются они "кладом".
~3. *Клали* что-то в сталь, из которой ковали дорогие мечи. По мне - гораздо более правдоподобно. Но сомнения основаны на том, что добавки в сталь действительно могли быть, но вряд ли их назвали бы "кладом". 
~4. Версия, которую я не могу проверить и поэтому сказать ничего не могу. Кладенец - меч в ножнах, куда его *вкладывали*.
~5. "Сказочная" версия о том, что сам меч был *кладом*. В смысле: нельзя было сделать, только найти. Базируется на том, что на Руси до монголов почти не знали искусства изготовления оружейной стали. Не лишено оснований, хорошей оружейной стали на Руси действительно не знали, во всяком случае она сильно уступала не только арабским, но и близлежашим "источникам".

Answer (score 4):

В древние времена меч-кладенец был особенным оружием!
Вы абсолютно правы, когда говорите о мастерстве русских кузнецов, да само название тоже говорит о вашей правильной версии про укладывание(куда-либо).
А было всё примерно вот так:
Кузнец изготавливал из железа разной твёрдости пруты и скорывал их в "косу", затем он вытягивал эту заготовку и ещё раз скручивал(процесс мог быть очень длительным).
Когда скруток по мнению мастера было достаточно он придавал заготовке слегка увеличенную, в отличие от желаемой, форму клинка.
Затем в специальный день(тогда ведали такое) или ночь кузнец проводил обряд уклада этой заготовки(произносились заветные слова), для чего выбиралось место со специальными свойствами почвы и именно там закапывался будущий меч, а сверху обычно воздвигался огромный валун.
Спустя 10 лет(по разным источникам даты варьируются от 5 до 100 и более лет) эта заготовка извлекалась и отковывалась окончательно.
Самое сложное в изготовлении такого меча в том, что извлечённую заготовку надо было проковывать за один раз, иначе металл терял свои восхитительные свойства(во время 10-летнего погребения окисление избавляло заготовку от ненужных примесей и создавало новые химические элементы, которые наделяли во время однократного нагрева поразительными свойствами будущий клинок).
Но и это ещё не всё, остывать только что прокованный клинок должен был тоже специально.
Кузнец садился на коня и мчался во весь опор, а сам в это время очень громко кричал заветные слова и рисовал в воздухе магические руны, призывая душу клинка войти в него.
Таким магическим обрядом меч-кладенец "отпускался" .
Было не много кузнецов-волхвов и такие мечи были крайней редкостью, поэтому стоили запредельно дорого.
Такими мечами легко рубилась любая сталь и булатные/дамасские мечи, хотя булат был очень распространён на Руси в дохристианскую эпоху величия(он так и назывался Северный булат за свойство выдерживать низкие температуры наших широт, в отличие от тюркского булата, который тут выкрашивался).
был рад помочь, всего доброго))

Comment: Очень интересно! А насколько правда?

Comment: А ни насколько.
Нигде нет источников. Я этот вопрос прорабптвал основательно, подной версии не видел даже близко.

Answer (score 3):

Скорей всего тут имеется в виду меч изготовленный по определённой технологии.Конечно проще всего сделать меч, из цельного куска металла, но технологии того времени не позволяли получить таким образом сталь хорошего качества, подобные мечи быстро покрывались зазубринами и ломались. Поэтому мечи хорощего качества сваривали из нескольких прутьев железа и стали. Вот как описывает технологию изготовления древнерусских мечей Ал-Бируни (не позднее 1050г):

> Русы выделывали свои мечи из шапуркана, а долы посредине их из нармохана, чтобы придать им прочность при ударе, предотвратить их хрупкость. Ал-фулад (сталь) не выносит холода их зим и ломается при ударе. Когда они познакомились с фарандом (т. е. с узорчатым булатом.-Лег.), то изобрели для долов плетенье из длинных проволок (изготовленных) из обеих разновидностей железа-шапуркана и женского (т. е. железа). И стали получаться у них на сварных плетениях при погружении (в травитель) вещи удивительные и редкостные, такие, какие они желали и намеревались получить. Ал-фаранд же (рисунок) не получается соответственно намерению при изготовлении (меча) и не приходит по желанию, но он случаен.

Тут описана технология наварки стальных ("из шапуркана") лезвий на железную ("из нормохана") основу клинка.  Ал-Бируни также говорит я о превосходстве техники изготовления узора на клинках мечей у русских оружейников. При соответствующей комбинации железных и стальных полос на основе клинка древнерусский кузнец мог получить любой заданный рисунок с одинаковым ритмом по всей полосе, что особенно и удивляло Бируни. Булатный же рисунок, как известно из опытов П. П. Аносова, случаен, так как при кристаллизации тигельной стали в каждом отдельном случае получается свой рисунок структурной неоднородности.
 Но как всегда было одно но: булатные мечи боялись северных морозов: сталь становилась хрупкой и легко ломалась. Поэтому на Руси производили "сварочный" булат. Такой булат назывался "дамаск" Брали куски проволоки или полосы железа, стали, их поочередно **складывали** (железо-сталь-железо-сталь и т. д.) и затем много раз проковывали, много раз прокручивали, перекручивали эти полосы, складывали их гармошкой. Словом, чем больше кузнец потратит времени на проковку металла, тем лучше получится клинок.

Возможно мечи изготовленные по подобной технологии и называли кладенцами.

Answer (score 2):

Однажды не так давно, уже не помню с чего, но заинтересовался вопросом происхождения этого слова и выяснил, что практически все пытаются этот чудо меч куда-то покласть, укласть, вкласть... и т. д…(та же самая история и со словом **КЛАД**)

...и решил подойти с другой стороны. Слово КЛАД - что оно означает на других языках? И о эврика! **ПЛАКИРОВАННЫЙ** - на 12 языках!!! (это только то, что я нашел в гугле переводчике).

Плакирова́ние (фр. *plaquer* — накладывать, покрывать), те́рмомехани́ческое покры́тие — нанесение на поверхность металлических листов, плит, проволоки, труб тонкого слоя другого металла или сплава термомеханическим способом.

Тут кстати не мешает вспомнить,  какими свойствами обладал этот чудо-меч. Он сам рубил. Т.е. был очень лёгок и остр. Получается, что меч был выкован из легкого металла и плакирован (на хорватском-*pokriven, odjeven*. На-словацком-*oblečený, odetý v, odetý*. На болгарском и македонском-*облечени*, и т.д.) т.е. **покрыт, одет, облачен** каким-то более твердым и тяжелым металлом.

В связи с этим возможно должен возникнуть вопрос-  а на столько ли плохо всё было на Руси с искусством обработки металлов? А может быть мы слишком мало знаем историю Древней Руси?

Comment: Было бы действительно неплохо - не мотались бы всякие Иваны-царевичи в тридесятые царства за непонятно чем прельстивших их кладенцами.

Answer (score 2):

Уклад, укладка, класть, кладут. Русский кузнец отливал несколько кусков металла с различной твердостью, обжигал их в печи, после остывания от них откалывались кусочки металла, которые он укладывал особым образом нагревал в горне и проковывал, повторяя эту операцию несколько раз. Далее термообработка одна из ключевых операций, можно при этом читать заклинания но важнее подобрать правильный режим закалки и отпуска. Такой меч по качеству оружейной стали не уступал японским мечам

Comment: Вы хоть знаете, что русские мечи сильно уступали по качеству заморским? 
Какой смысл чуть ли не обожествлять то, что мог сделать любой кузнец?

Comment: Качество большинства японских боевых мечей очень плохое. Железа на островах мало, и по своим характеристикам, катаны значительно уступают зарубежным аналогам.

@behemothus, а с чего вы решили, что русские мечи были хуже заморских? По свидетельству арабов мечи русов были вполне себе хорошего качества.  В 943-944 гг. мусульмане грабили могилы русов, погибших в походе у города Бердаа. Ибн Мискавейх сообщает, что они "извлекли оттуда мечи, которые имеют большой спрос и в наши дни (*середина Х в*) по причине их остроты и превосходства"

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю версию, что кладенцами называли мечи, найденные в земле, например, в курганах. Часто эти мечи были высочайшего качества, что могут подтвердить даже современные "копатели" - многие "кочевые" мечи до сих пор сохранили гибкость металла - через 1200-1500 лет после захоронения.
Вдобавок, подобному мечу ,действительно, могли приписываться магические свойства, связанные с культами умерших предков, "матушки-сырой земли" и т.п.
Сами мечи были настолько дороги в ту эпоху и редки в деревнях, что даже двухсотлетний, на тот момент, меч превращался в самое грозное оружие против дубин, копий, топоров и вил.

Answer (score 1):

Гла́диус или как правильно читать гла́дий (лат. Gladius - меч) – общее название для четырёх типов римских мечей. Само же слово гладиус вполне возможно происходит от кельтского «kladyos» («меч»), хотя некоторые эксперты считают, что этот термин может происходить и от латинского «clades» («повреждение, рана). Отсюда прослеживается: кладуос -гладиус - кладес - кладенец. Поскольку - кельтский, латинский и праславянский языки имели много общих слов и оборотов, так и мог появиться меч-кладенец т.е.: меч-меч, меч-повреждающий, меч-ранящий.

Answer (score 0):

По мнению Пехи Дыырдака, меч-кладенец - 
это великолепный железный меч,
закаленный особым способом - в колодце.
Колодец - источник холодной, минерализованной воды большого объема.
Закалка кованого меча в такой воде и придает мечу-кладенцу уникальные свойства.

-
Ведь
:
В восточно-европейских странах: Словении, Болгарии... 
kladenac 
колодец, источник холодной чистой воды.

Answer (score 0):

Кладенец  ---  К-ЛАД-ЕНЕЦ. Обладание этим мечом означало овладение своим телом в совершенстве. Правильно писали, что кладенец нельзя изготовить, его можно только добыть(найти). Но штука в том, что найти его можно лишь пойдя за мудростью народной, т.е. овладев знаниями и умениями предков, т.е. генетической памятью, сокрытой в костях(костном мозге). К-ладу - к гармонии, стремился обладатель кладенца, к овладению своим совершенным оружием - мудростью кощея(родовая память).

Comment: Эээээ, а кости-то тут каким боком?!